# AutoIndent bracket in Java Swing JeditorPane

Tags: java, swing, jeditorpane

I am working on a code-editor in java and i want to know how to auto-indent  using brackets (open and close) like an actual code editor .

like this 1:

```
Array PrincipalVar = (Var => (OtherVar =>  (var3 => 3,
                                            var4 => 8,
                                            var6 => 1) 
                             ), 
                      Var2 => (var => 1))
```

Editor is a JEditorPane. I tried some code, but nothing seem to work.
I have already file contening code, and I want to Re-Indent this file. 
Code I already tried :

```
public String indentFileTry() throws FileNotFoundException{
        LinkedList<Integer> inBracket = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        String currentLine = "";
        Scanner indent = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
        String ptu = "";
        while(indent.hasNextLine()) {
            currentLine =   indent.nextLine();
            currentLine = currentLine.trim(); 
            char[] line = currentLine.toCharArray();
            int i = 0;
            while(i < line.length){ //Here I define the position of the Bracet for Indentation
                if(line[i] == '('){

                    inBracket.addFirst(i);
                }

                i++;
            }
            if(!inBracket.isEmpty()){//here I indent with the position of the bracket and I remove the first(First In First Out)
                if(!currentLine.contains(")")){
                    int spaceadded = 0;
                    String space ="";
                    while(spaceadded <= inBracket.getFirst()){
                        spaceadded++; space += " ";
                    }

                        currentLine = space + currentLine;
                        inBracket.removeFirst();

                }else if(currentLine.contains(")")){
                    int spaceadded = 0;
                    String space ="";
                    while(spaceadded <= inBracket.getFirst()){
                        spaceadded++; space += " ";
                    }

                        currentLine =    space + currentLine;

                    inBracket.removeFirst();
                }
            }


            ptu += currentLine +"\n";

        }
        indent.close() ; 
        System.out.println(ptu);
        return ptu;




    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the response, What I do is easy. 
I made a LinkedList, and I use it like a FILO (First in Last out) like this :

```
public String indentFile() throws FileNotFoundException{
    LinkedList<Integer> positionBracket = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    String currentLine = "";
    Scanner indent = new Scanner(new FileReader(f));
    String stringIndented = "";

    while(indent.hasNextLine()) {

        currentLine =   indent.nextLine();
        currentLine = currentLine.trim(); 
        char[] lineInChar = currentLine.toCharArray();
        int i = 0;
        int spaceadded = 0;
        String space ="";
        if(!positionBracket.isEmpty()){

                while(spaceadded <= positionBracket.getFirst()){
                    spaceadded++; 
                    space += " "; // We put same space like the last opened bracket

                }

        }

        while(i < lineInChar.length){

            if(lineInChar[i] == '('){ //If opened bracket I put the position in the top of the Filo


                positionBracket.addFirst(new Integer(i));

            }
            if(lineInChar[i] == ')' && !countCom){
                positionBracket.removeFirst(); //If closed bracket I remove the position on the top of the Filo

            }



            i++;
        }
        stringIndented += space + currentLine +"\n";
        }
    }
    return stringIndented;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you expect automatically indentation you won't get such code. You should implement it yourself adding \n spaces (or \t) chars to format your code. JEditorPane does not understand your code logic. You (with your code parser) should define parent/child relation for lines of code you have.

One example for the case when parent/children are defined is XML. See [the XMLEditorKit](http://java-sl.com/xml_editor_kit.html) where nodes are indented.

Comment: I edited my post, I use a String, and after I put this string in the JEditorPanel. 
But the code don't work.